# Local virtual sites only working on initial hit

Tags: angular, apache, localhost, virtualhost

EDIT: It's most definitely something to do with the Angular. I modified my index file on one of the sites to remove all Angular references and the site loaded. I went back and put it back in then went to the folder I had the Angular 14 project in and typed `ng serve` and now all the sites work! I'm still not sure why the other sites are now tied to this one folder, though. Can I separate them?

For some reason, my local virtual sites only work the first time they're hit in any given browser inside any given profile. The second hit attempt results in a CONNECTION_REFUSED. (See image)

I've cleared cache and files multiple times to no avail. I've tried this across multiple profiles on my computer as well as multiple browsers within the profile. Each time I can hit a site on a new browser, it fails the second time. Based on what's happening, I'm guessing it's a configuration thing in Apache (2.4) as that's the only common factor across everything. But, I didn't change anything in Apache recently, so I'm not sure what happened. I've restarted Apache several times as well but that didn't help.

The only thing that I'm thinking MAY have had an effect, but I'm not sure how since I never touched the webserver in the process is: I don't recall if the timing exactly lined up, but it was roughly the same time that I noticed this happening that I updated to angular 14 on my machine to play around with updating my angular knowledge. My local sites are all in AngularJS. I was using `ng serve` to work on the new stuff. But it was all localized to its own directory. Could that have messed up the main web server somehow?

[image]